# Convert string to np.nan

Tags: python

Say I have a list such as the one below:

```
["1","2","nan","4","5"]
```

I would like to convert the numbers to integers/floats and the string "nan" to np.nan

I want to do this without pandas if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert it to `np.array`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = ["1","2","nan","4","5"]
>>> np.array(l,dtype=float)
array([ 1.,  2., nan,  4.,  5.])
>>> np.array(l,dtype=float).tolist()
[1.0, 2.0, nan, 4.0, 5.0]
```